# Ocaml and return type (graph theory)

Tags: ocaml, graph-theory, return-type

I'm just a begginer in Ocaml, and I wanted to study the graph theory, but with implementations in Ocaml. And I've got a trouble to do something : I just wanted to list the connected components of a graph by using a Depth first search. So, I did :

```
#open "stack" ;;

let non_empty pile = 
    try push (pop pile) pile ; true with Empty -> false ;;


let connected_comp g = 
    let already_seen = make_vect (vect_length g) false in
    let comp = [] in

    let dfs s lst = 
        let totreat = new () in
        already_seen.(s) <- true; push s totreat;

        let rec add_neighbour l = match l with
            | [] -> ()
            | q::r when already_seen.(q) = false -> push q totreat; already_seen.(q) <- true; add_neighbour r
            | q::r -> add_neighbour r
        in

        while non_empty totreat do
            let s = pop totreat in
            already_seen.(s) <- true;
            (* we want to add s to the list lst *) s::lst;
            add_neighbour g.(s);
        done
    in  


    let rec head_list l = match l with
        | [] -> failwith "Empty list"
        | p::q -> p
    in  
    let rec aux comp t = match t with
        | t when t = vect_length g -> comp
        | t when already_seen.(t) = true -> aux comp (t+1)
        | t -> aux ((dfs t [])::comp) (t+1) (* we want that dfs t [] return the list lst modified *)
    in aux comp 0;;
```

And I obtain :

```
>       | t -> (dfs t [])::comp ; aux  comp (t+1) (* we want that dfs t [] return the list lst modified *)
>              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Warning : this expression is of type unit list,
but is used with the type unit.
connected_comp : int list vect -> unit list = <fun>
- : unit list = []
- : unit = ()
```

Of course, I'm not surprised. But what I want to do is that the function `dfs` return the list sent on argument (the `lst` list) but modified, and here it's not the case as the function is of type unit, cause it return nothing. But in Ocaml, as the language is made for returning the last expression I think, I don't know how to do. I could as well use recursive algorithm for the `dfs` function, as, through filtering, it would permit me to return the list, but I just wanted to learn about Ocaml, and so modified (even if it's not optimal) my algorithm.

Someone could help me, please ?

**Edit :** As we ask me, I will try to reduce my code and get to the point. So, I have the function `dfs` which correspond to a Depth first search (for a graph)

```
let dfs s lst = 
    let totreat = new () in
    already_seen.(s) <- true; push s totreat;

    let rec add_neighbour l = match l with
        | [] -> ()
        | q::r when already_seen.(q) = false -> push q totreat; already_seen.(q) <- true; add_neighbour r
        | q::r -> add_neighbour r
    in

    while non_empty totreat do
        let s = pop totreat in
        already_seen.(s) <- true;
        (* we want to add s to the list lst *) s::lst;
        add_neighbour g.(s);
    done
in
```

(alreadyseen is a vector of boolean, defined previously)

And my only problem is that I want that the function return the list `lst` modified (in the loop while), when, at this point, it's a unit function.

I tried to define lst as a reference, but then I don't know how to return it...

I hope it's more clear, I'm not familiar with all of this at the moment...

Thank you !

Comment: Try writing a minimal version of your code that only includes the definition of `dfs` and does not rely on external data types. It will make it easier for us to help you. Also note that if you want to "learn about OCaml" learning to write recursive function and avoiding side effects is the point.

Comment: Note that the code example is in Caml Light not in OCaml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a degraded version of your code that demonstrate one way to do what you want.

```
let non_empty _ = false

let dfs s lst =
  let local_lst = ref lst in

  while non_empty () do
    (*do stuff here*)
    let s = 1 in
    local_lst := s::!local_lst;
    (*do stuff here*)
  done;
  !local_lst
```

I first initialize a local mutable value `local_lst` to the list `lst` given as an argument. I then update this value in the `while` loop. And finally I return the value stored in `local_lst`.

Comment: It's just perfect, thank you very much ! Is it also a possibility to ask that the lst parameter of the function dfs be a reference to modify it directly and return it at the end ?
In any case, thank you very much !

Comment: Yes `lst` can be a reference, if you do so you don't need to return it at the end because the reference will be modified. Then, the return type of the function will be `unit` and you can reuse the reference you gave as an argument.

Comment: Thank you very much for all those explanations ! :)

Comment: But using a reference is really not the ocaml way. Generally in functional languages you return new values instead of modifying anything in place.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow is right. You should learn to not use mutable values, you wil see the benefits very quickly because debugging becomes a lot easier.